# Dynamics CRM Plugin Run ssrs report and convert into pdf throws error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamic-sql, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to run report and attach with email as pdf.
MS Dynamis crm 2016 Onpremise server.
SQL server 2014 on another server.
when i run plugin its shows "file not found error" report

Comment: When getting file not found error, usually best thing to do is to compare the location you are trying to get it from and the actual location of the file, and most probably you will find that they are different.

But, when you are posting a question, you could at least try to give enough information and description, like maybe some piece of your code in the part where you are getting the error. You cannot write one sentence question and expect someone to magically solve your problem.

Also which CRM version are you experiencing it? Is it 2011 or 2013, as you have tags for both.

Comment: thank you this error are resolved.

Comment: but i am facing another issue and the error is
Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): POProcess: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: An error has occurred during report processing.
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing. Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Query execution failed for dataset 'POData'. System.Exception: For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

Comment: using RE2005 & RS2005.asmx web service
_parameters = rs.GetReportParameters(_report, _historyID, _forRendering, _values, _credentials);
if (_parameters != null){
  if (_parameters.Length > 0) {
       parameters[0] = new DLIT_POProcess.RE2005.ParameterValue();
       parameters[0].Label = _parameters[0].Name;
       parameters[0].Name = _parameters[0].Name;
       parameters[0].Value = subPOId;
       }
 }
rsExec.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");
results = rsExec.Render(format, deviceInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);